# Assigning values to properties in a singleton implemented with static let in Swift

Tags: swift, singleton, value-type, reference-type

From reading it seems like the best advice for creating a singleton in Swift is to use `static let` like this:

```
struct GameManager {
  static let defaultManager = GameManager()
  var gameScore = 0
  var saveState = 0
  private init() {}
}

GameManager.defaultManager.gameScore = 1024 // Error
GameManager.defaultManager.saveState = 12 // Error
let score = GameManager.defaultManager.gameScore
let savedProgress = GameManager.defaultManager.saveState
```

Because the `defaultManager` is declared as a constant (with "let"), there is an error when I try to assign `gameScore` and `saveState`.

[image: playground error cannot assign to property]

I'm running Xcode 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o) with Swift 2.0 (swiftlang-700.0.57.3 clang-700.0.72).

If I change the `defaultManager` to be declared as a variable (with "var"), will it no longer be considered a proper singleton?

---

If I change the GameManager to be declared as a class instead of a structure, then the code works as expected.

```
class GameManager {
  static let defaultManager = GameManager()
  var gameScore = 0
  var saveState = 0
  private init() {}
}

GameManager.defaultManager.gameScore = 1024 // No error, why?
GameManager.defaultManager.saveState = 12 // No error, why?
let score = GameManager.defaultManager.gameScore // 1,024
let savedProgress = GameManager.defaultManager.saveState // 12
```

Can you explain why the reference-type class is better for implementing the singleton than the value-type structure?

Comment: is there anything i can help you with or you are ok ?

Comment: Your answer makes sense. I had to get my mind around why I shouldn't implement a singleton as a structure. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really change it because on your struct you have a `let` constant named `defaultManager`. As you know already a struct is a copy type while a class is a pass by reference one. if you want to use it as a struct you will have to replace that `let` with `var` instead. Another take of this problem is to change the struct to a `class` that way you will be able to change the `defaultManager` value although it is declared as a `let`.

cheers

edit: The main difference in your code is that when you have a constant in a `class` and you change that constant you are actually referring to its address rather than its actual value.Same doesn't happen with a `struct` cause as a value type you can't do that call by reference thingy you do with `class` and so you are forced to have a constant(`let`) value that cannot be mutated. Change the `let` to `var` inside your `struct` and see the magic happen